# mysql transaction error handling

Tags: mysql, transactions

```
 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING, NOT FOUND 
BEGIN 
    ROLLBACK; 
END;
START TRANSACTION;      

    UPDATE tbl_order SET TransactionID="abc" WHERE OrderID=1;
    UPDATE tbl_order SET TransactionID="xyz" WHERE OrderID=;
    UPDATE tbl_order SET TransactionID="zzz" WHERE OrderID=13;


COMMIT;
```

for some reason order 1 and 13 are filled without rollback and  i get syntax error for the exit hadler.

```
Query:  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING, NOT FOUND BEGIN ROLLBACK

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING, NOT FOUND 
BEGIN 
    ROLLBACK' at line 1
```

can someone help me figure out what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

**UPDATE tbl_order SET TransactionID="xyz" WHERE OrderID=;**

is intentional

Comment: Shot in the dark: is the semicolon after `rollback` prematurely ending the exit handler?

Comment: so anyway i went ahead and did it with code instead of using mysql query to handle errors . Assuming an open connection

    MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
    try{
      cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      cmd.Transaction.Commit();
    }catch (Exception ex){
       cmd.Transaction.Rollback();
       dbLog.ErrorFormat("*** Transaction Rollback: {0}\n Params: {1}\n Ex: {2}\n", strSQL, ex.InnerException);
    }

Comment: also it doesn't seem to give me any errors if the sql is formatted correctly and the code is in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe exit handlers can only be used in stored procedures. The documentation doesn't explicitly state this, but alludes to

> Conditions may arise during stored program execution that require special handling

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/condition-handling.html

Comment: any example for handling transaction error and rollback

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite outdated topic, but I encountered the same error when declaring my own procedure with transaction and error handling. The above procedure looks well, something OP didn't copy as it seems. **The order is important** and it should look like this:

1. Procedure declaration
2. Declaration of variables
3. ERROR HANDLING
4. Start transaction
5. Statements
6. Commit
7. End

In my case, it looks like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE pAddUser(IN _nick VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
    DECLARE doesUserExist BOOLEAN;
    DECLARE accountCreationDate DATE;

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;

    SET doesUserExist = (SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE nick=_nick));
    IF NOT doesUserExist THEN
        SET accountCreationDate = CURDATE();
        INSERT INTO tblUser (nick, accountCreation) VALUES (_nick, CURDATE());
    ELSE
        SELECT CONCAT("Nick '", _nick, "' is in use!") AS 'Console output';
    END IF;

    COMMIT;

END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```